# pykinect2 depth frame truncated

Tags: python, pygame, kinect-v2

I am trying to use PyKinect2 module to get the depth frames from a Kinect v2 device. I've followed the examples provided [here](https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2/tree/master/examples). I am able to see the depth frames, but they appear in the PyGame window truncated, although the size of the frame is 512x424 as it should be.

[depth_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7htF.png)

I use the `get_last_depth_frame()` method provided by PyKinect2 and draw it on the surface with the following code.

```
def draw_depth_frame(self, frame, target_surface):
    target_surface.lock()
    address = self._kinect.surface_as_array(target_surface.get_buffer())
    ctypes.memmove(address, frame.ctypes.data, frame.size)
    del address
    target_surface.unlock()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment. So I write it here. 
I think you need 3 channels to stuff the memory to required length. 
Try this

```
f8=np.uint8(frame.clip(1,4000)/16.)    
frame8bit=np.dstack((f8,f8,f8))
```

Then memmove from frame8bit instead of original frame.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the `Surface` size to 24bit:

In `__init__(self)` function:

```
self._depth_frame_surface = pygame.Surface((self._kinect.depth_frame_desc.Width,
self._kinect.depth_frame_desc.Height),
0, 24)
```

Then you should change `self._screen` to take the depth frame width and height:

```
self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self._kinect.depth_frame_desc.Width,
self._kinect.depth_frame_desc.Height), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE,
32)
```

Finally, draw the depth frame like @Shuangjun Suggested:

```
def draw_depth_frame(self, frame, target_surface):
    target_surface.lock()
    f8 = np.uint8(frame.clip(1, 4000) / 16.)
    frame8bit = np.dstack((f8, f8, f8))
    address = self._kinect.surface_as_array(target_surface.get_buffer())
    ctypes.memmove(address, frame8bit.ctypes.data, frame8bit.size)
    del address
    target_surface.unlock()
```